# Including resource files in a Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am porting an app to Windows 8 Metro, and it has a number of resource files (e.g. bitmap files, xml files, binary files) which are needed in order for it to run.  How do I include these in the app and how do I access them from C++?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the resources and set their build-action to be "content".
After that, you can use directly refer to the images in XAML.

```
<Image Source="images/logo.png" />
```

and in C#

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appx:///images/logo.png');
var file = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

[More>>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965325.aspx)

Comment: I am new to Windows 8 Metro so bear with me.  I want to be able to open and read a binary file.  I added the file to the assets folder of the project and then added it to the project.  I right clicked on the file and set 'Content' to 'Yes' (note that this dialog does NOT look like the one above)  I then tried to access the file using the C++ version of the code above and I get an exception thrown when I call 'GetResults()' on the 'file' that is returned from the 'getFileFromApplicationuriAsync' call.  Are there any sample apps that show how to access binary files from app resources?  Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx
You might find it in this set of pages

Comment: Thanks again for the input.  I have seen that article before, and I looked through it again, but I cannot see how it shows how to add binary resource files and access them in the app.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Just for the hell of it, I tried simply calling fopen("assets/myfile.bin", "rb") and low and behold, it seems to work just fine.  Is this a legitimate way to access binary files?  I took a look at some installed Metro apps and they did seem to have extensive file structures.  Once my app is bundled and installed, will the app have read access to all of these files?  Thanks.